# Why do you need a &nbsp; in IE for this break to work?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I wrote this bit of code because I wanted images to appear in the same place regardless of how many bullet points the user fills out in the CMS. IF they don't fill in a spot for a bulleted link or text, it just puts a break rule. What I don't get is why IE requires a   before the break rule for the break rule to take effect. It worked fine Chrome, FF, and Opera without it. What I'm referring to is in the  statement.

`<cfif len(promos.link1text) gt 0 AND len(promos.link1url) gt 0>

    <li><a href="#promos.link1url#">#promos.link1text#</a></li>

 <cfelseif len(promos.link1url) gt 0>

    <li><a href="#promos.link1url#">#promos.link1url#</a></li>

        <cfelseif len(promos.link1text) gt 0>

            <li>#promos.link1text#</li>

        <cfelse>&nbsp;<br/>
        </cfif>`

Comment: I removed my answer because I did not pay attention to the <li> tags  and only addressed the syntax error in the <br/>

Answer (score 1):

That code will generate invalid HTML - a `<ul>` or `<ol>` cannot directly contain a `<br />` tag. This is probably why you're getting inconsistent results.

Comment: What happens if you neglect the space in <br />? I haven't been putting that space in there ever, and this is the first time I've had issues, and apparently they aren't even related.

Comment: The correct markup is <br /> for XHTML. Depending on which DOCTYPE you choose and browser you view the markup with will determine how forgiving that browser will render syntax.

Comment: I think the space is a matter of preference. In the XHTML specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6 I don't see anything that says a space is required and the samples don't show a space.  I prefer not to add the space as I find it much easier to read and I have yet to find any browser issues.

Comment: To make it clear: **there does *not* need to be a space in `<br/>` tags**.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you will want to run your code through validation to see what syntax improvements you can make:

http://validator.w3.org/check/referer